Python Logging Color Output In Terminal Without ANSI Escape Code In File
this is more of a 2 part question regarding logging and terminal output.

How, if possible to log color output in terminal with color, but don't have them display the ANSI escape code when redirecting (>), or output to log file? I try not to use any external library with this if possible.

I understand you can use ANSI escape code like \x1b[31m (foreground red) or \x1b[43m (background yellow) to display color in terminal. When I use redirect (>), or output to file, they display ESC[36m in the log file.
Python have a rich library that can output stylized text in terminal, and when I tried it, it output the result to file without the ANSI escape code.

I was wondering how they achieve this? I read some of the documentation, and skim some of the code, but still cannot figure out how they are doing this.


Does this answer your question? How do I detect whether sys.stdout is attached to terminal or not?

@Woodford, this is interesting, I will have to experiment with this one and see

It should not be difficult to implement what you need - in fact it seems you are halfway there with your knowledge of escape codes. There is a very nice answer here which fleshes this out.
The other half of the equation is to separate out what goes to the console (with the escape codes) and what goes anywhere else. This is why the referenced answer applies the escape codes using a Formatter, which in turn is only applied to a StreamHandler. What you need therefore is an additional handler - a FileHandler with its own Formatter - to respond to the same logging events, but in a different way (i.e. writing to a log file).
I apologise for not responding about the 'rich' package - I am not familiar with it - but unless you need it for other purposes too, I wouldn't bother with it. Your issue is really a logger handling/formatting one, and the logging module is both very powerful and well-documented.
A note about activating color output in a Windows console: you may need to add os.system('color') to your code.
